# Merging nested tables in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a linq query that gets data from an OData Reporting service 
So far so good, but when I return my data like this :

```
select new {TimesheetActual , TimesheetLine,Timesheet, TimesheetProject,TimesheetTask, subTv, TimesheetResource, subRes, pLeft}
```

It returns as a collection of nested collections.

For my service I need one big table with every column from every record. 
I know this is possible by explicitly naming every column in the select statement like this:

```
select new { TimesheetActual.Column1, TimesheetActual.Column2, .., TimesheetLine.Column1,.., TimesheetProject.Column1,..}
```

But due to the massive amount of columns I'm  a little reluctant to do it this way.

So my question, is there any way to either merge the collections or another way to get the same result without having to specify 100+ columns?